# Make error when installing wifi adapter drivers

Tags: drivers, make, raspberrypi, ralink

Just installed Ubuntu Server Standard onto my Raspberry Pi from https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/

I have a Canakit Wifi Adapter, and am attempting to install the driver: http://www.canakit.com/ckxw1000

I have downloaded the file, decompressed it, however when running make, this is the output:

```
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/tools'
/home/ubuntu/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/ubuntu/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/4.1.19-v7+/build     SUBDIRS=/home/ubuntu/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.1.19-v7+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:388: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Kernels 4.6 and newer are not compatible, because the net stack has be modified, roll back to 4.3 or 4.5 version then make will work and also the driver works well.